# RADAsyncUpload goes beyond the container

Tags: telerik

In the Demo of RadAsyncUpload at https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx, on inspecting the select button, the input of type "file" goes beyond the container. How can I make it stay within the boundary of the select button?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Width and Height to the .ruFileInput class override as shown in the screenshot I captured for you:
[image]